# Invalid Json response with API CURL PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I am trying to call an API using CURL , and the supplier is only allowed x-www-form-urlencoded's content-type, but it responds XML with JSON within it.

However, in PHP's curl response, it will remove all xml tag. This is the respond I got :

> {
> "Description":"MERCEDES BENZ C 300 AMG LINE MY17 W205 FACELIFT 9 SP AUTOMATIC 9G TRONIC",
> "RegistrationYear":"2020",
> "CarMake":{
> "CurrentTextValue":"MERCEDES BENZ"
> },
> "CarModel":{
> "CurrentTextValue":"C"
> },
> "MakeDescription":{
> "CurrentTextValue":"MERCEDES BENZ"
> },
> "ModelDescription":{
> "CurrentTextValue":"C"
> },
> "Seats":"5",
> "Body":"SEDAN",
> } The registered car is a MERCEDES BENZ C 300 AMG

The problem is at last "sentence" where it is not a valid json string, is there any way to remove unwanted "sentence" after the last } i.e. the "The registered car is a MERCEDES BENZ C 300 AMG"

any idea???

Comment: _"in PHP's curl response, it will remove all xml tag"_... this seems extremely unlikely. What leads you to believe this? If you're just `echo`-ing the response, you should make sure you're not viewing it as HTML. Add `header("Content-type: text/xml");` before you `echo` anything. Of course, I'm just guessing but wouldn't have to if you included your code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the last sentence is fairly simple:

```
<?php
// Assuming we have the response as a string:
$response_string = '{ "Description":"MERCEDES BENZ C 300 AMG LINE MY17 W205 FACELIFT 9 SP AUTOMATIC 9G TRONIC", "RegistrationYear":"2020", "CarMake":{ "CurrentTextValue":"MERCEDES BENZ" }, "CarModel":{ "CurrentTextValue":"C" }, "MakeDescription":{ "CurrentTextValue":"MERCEDES BENZ" }, "ModelDescription":{ "CurrentTextValue":"C" }, "Seats":"5", "Body":"SEDAN", } The registered car is a MERCEDES BENZ C 300 AMG';

// We get the find index of the last closing lambda/parenthesis using strpos
$last_parenthesis = strpos( $response_string, '}', -1 );

// Then use that index to trim the json-string to the correct length using substr
$trimmed_response_string = substr( $response_string, 0, $last_parenthesis );

// Then use json_decode to cast the json-string as a multidimensional variable
$json_data = json_decode( $trimmed_response_string );

var_dump( $json_data );
exit;
```

Hopefully that helps

Comment: Hi Thanks! tested and the idealogy is correct but not sure why it returned blank ! However I manage to do some tiny modification from your script and it shows!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just find the last occurrence of } and remove everything after it like so:

```php
$content = "..."; // The content you posted

// Get the json up until and including the last }
$json = substr($content, 0, strrpos($content, '}') + 1);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks! tested and the method is correct but it shows the sentence instead of remove from your script, but i found solution which to remove it instead, that using the same idea from your propose script! Thanks!

Comment: My bad, I'll update it, it was late 